# JSON-SCHEMA arbitrary names on top level

Tags: jsonschema, feathersjs, ajv

I'm using json-schema with a nodeJs backend called 'feathers-plus' which validate data using popular ajv.

I've got two objects -> ObjectA & ObjectB where ObjectA is the parent.
ObjectA contain a collection of ObjectB that have arbitrary names defined by patternProperties and which is objects:

```
exchanges: {
  type: 'object',
  patternProperties: {
    "^[A-Za-z]+$": {
      type: 'object'
    }
  },
  additionalProperties: false
},
```

ObjectB (which is an exchange in my case) start with this arbitrary key name on top-level and then contain itself more properties (on second level and so on).

The problem is I don't know how to define these arbitrary keys names. I know how to define it on second level and more deeply using the example above for exchanges. But on top, I suppose I can't write something like this:

```
"^[A-Za-z]+$": {
  type: 'object'
}
```

With feathers-plus, we can separate our logical objects in services. In my case here, the top service is called "configs" and the child one "exchanges".

Any help would be grateful.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: as requested, I post my current schemas for both objects:

Parent ObjectA ->

```
let schema = {
  title: 'Configs',
  description: 'Configs database.',

  required: [
    'name',
    'bot',
    'GUI',
    'ws',
    'createdAt',
    'updatedAt'
  ],

  uniqueItemProperties: [

  ],

  properties: {
    id: { type: 'ID' },
    name: {},
    pairs: {
      type: 'object',
      patternProperties: {
        "^[A-Za-z]+$": {
          type: 'object'
        }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    },

    // THIS IS THE CONTAINER FOR EXCHANGES OBJECTS
    exchanges: {
      type: 'object',
      patternProperties: {
        "^[A-Za-z]+$": {
          type: 'object'
        }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    // END

    bot: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        debug: { type: 'boolean' },
        gui: { type: 'boolean' },
        period_storage_ticker: { type: 'number' },
        interval_ticker_update: { type: 'number' },
        timeout_buy: { type: 'number' },
        timeout_sell: { type: 'number' },
        WATCH_MODE: { type: 'boolean' },
        TELEGRAM_ENABLED: { type: 'boolean' },
        TELEGRAM_NICK: {},
        TOKEN: {},
        chat_id: { type: 'number' }
      },
      required: [
        'debug',
        'gui',
        'period_storage_ticker',
        'interval_ticker_update',
        'timeout_buy',
        'timeout_sell',
        'WATCH_MODE',
        'TELEGRAM_ENABLED',
        'TELEGRAM_NICK',
        'TOKEN',
        'chat_id'
      ]
    },
    GUI: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        enabled: { type: 'boolean' },
        start: { type: 'boolean' },
        port: { type: 'number' },
        https: { type: 'boolean' },
        key: {},
        cert: {},
        networktraffic: { type: 'boolean' },
        authentication: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            login: { type: 'boolean' },
            twoFA: { type: 'boolean' }
          },
          required: [
            'login',
            'twoFA'
          ]
        },
        notifications: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            trade: { type: 'boolean' },
            callback: { type: 'boolean' },
            error: { type: 'boolean' }
          },
          required: [
            'trade',
            'callback',
            'error'
          ]
        }
      },
      required: [
        'enabled',
        'start',
        'port',
        'https',
        'key',
        'cert',
        'networktraffic',
        'authentication',
        'notifications'
      ]
    },
    ws: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        port: { type: 'number' },
        clientport: { type: 'number' },
        hostname: {}
      },
      required: [
        'port',
        'clientport',
        'hostname'
      ]
    }
    createdAt: {},
    updatedAt: {}
  }
}
```

Child ObjectB ->

```
let schema = {
  title: 'Exchanges',
  description: 'Exchanges database.',

  // MY CURRENT EDIT (NOT WORKING)
  type: 'object',
  patternProperties: {
    "^[A-Za-z]+$": { type: 'boolean' }
  },
  additionalProperties: false,
  // END

  required: [

  ],

  uniqueItemProperties: [

  ],

  properties: {

  },
}
```

If I'm making a request and try to pass anything, it works and validation is not made. The same patternProperties set on a deeper level have no problem at all and is validated correctly.

Comment: What does your entire schema look like? At the top level you also need to define your schema using known keywords - you can't just write "exchanges", it will have to be inside a "properties" keyword (actually you can write "exchanges" but that means that you have defined a new keyword "exchanges" which is not known by your schema validator so it's not interpreted.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post with the full schemas.